# Devise registration flow errors -- not recognizing field values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration

first time posting here, so apologies if any format/structure errors!

I'm building a custom registration flow using Devise for my rails application, viewable on github here: github.com/BDecker19/theLIST  (i've also uploaded it to heroku, where it's showing the same problem.. foundersbloc-thelist.herokuapp.com)

Somehow I seem to have broken the flow, where now  when you try to create a new account, it fails validation saying the email and password fields can't be blank, even when they're filled out.

As the Devise controllers seem to be all internal, I can't quite figure out how to diagnose the issue?  I'm using Wicked to create a multistep profile creation process following sign in so have set a custom after_sign_in_path in my application controller, but doesn't seem like this is causing the issue?  I'm also using bootstrap, which maybe could be having some impact?  Otherwise, just not sure what it could be...

The sign_up was working before, although stupidly I deleted my git history when I recreated my repo to upload to Heroku.  Attaching some of the relevant code below, or let me know if any other information I should add!

Thanks so much in advance...

*views/devise/new.html.erb*

```
<div class="border-form-div">
  <h2>Ok, let's get you started...</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Email address' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Password confirmation' %>
    <%= f.submit "Continue to next step",:class=>'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

*models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_accessible :profile_complete, :name, :date_of_birth, :bio

end
```

*controllers/application_controller.rb*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


    # root action
    def home
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
            if current_user.profile_complete == true
                redirect_to root_path
            else 
                user_steps_path
            end
      end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled your code and ran the server.  You might watch the log file in the future, it shows mass assignment errors for the user fields.

Unless you REALLY need to start a new project with protected attributes gem, I would remove it.  It's a step for backward compatibility with rails 3 and mostly useful during the upgrade of existing projects from 3 to 4.

App works for me if:

Remove protected_attributes in Gemfile

```
gem 'protected_attributes`
```

Remove attr_accessible call in user model.  Everything works fine.

Comment: hey, thank you so much!  first off, both you and stackoverflow totally rock! :)

and that's great point... i haven't really understood how to use the log well, seems like i definitely should research a bit more.

in terms of removing the attr_accessible call -- just take out the "attr_accessible"?  Or how do i add those additional attributes?

Comment: you can remove that line entirely from user.rb -- Rails 4 uses strong parameters instead of attr_accessible.  When you create new models in your application, you'll need to use make sure you include them.  If you create your models/controllers with scaffolding `rails g scaffold model_name` it will automatically create the necessary param calls in your controller.  See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples for more examples